# codeception mark acceptance test as incomplete

Tags: codeception

What is the way to mark an acceptance test `(FooCest::incompleteTest())` as incomplete in codeception? Since the class in the acceptance test examples on the site don't implement another class it's probably some static call or with the `$I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of 2 ways of doing this.

You can throw a PHPUnit exception at the beginning of the test:

```
throw new \PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTestError('your message here');
```

Or you can use annotations:

```
/**
 * @incomplete
 */
```